# Can't get member count discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am using this code:

```py
for member in message.guild.members:
  members["membercount"] += 1
  if member.bot:
    members["bots"] += 1
```

For some reason i am getting that the total member count is 1 and there is 1 bot. The bot has administrator permissions and above all other roles. Is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: No, my discord wasn't updated. That was also the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have to enable `intents.members`. You can find more inside this [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).